# Laravel Migrations works but can't access data when needed

Tags: database, laravel-5

when i execute migrations it works and the table are created in my data base . but when i try to access to data from any table its tells me this

**QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `marques`)**

here the configuration in my .env file

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=koss
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=root
```

PLEASE HELP !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the command in your console to clear all configuration

```
php artisan config:clear
```

then run command to generate autoload files

```
composer dump
```

then try again if project works.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're trying to connect with in the error ("homestead") isn't the user in your .env file. If your migrations are running correctly, that means root@localhost can access the db "koss" with the password.  But it doesn't look like homestead can.

Comment: how can i fixe this ?